# Ubuntu dead slow after last update

Tags: 14.04, ati, performance

It's been a few days now. Everything is SLOW as hell. Going from a desktop to the next is slow. Unlocking my workstation kind of fades out the lock screen and fades in the desktop. The animation takes about 5 seconds! Any popup or window moving pegs a core for 1-2 seconds and is barely useable. Scrolling in Firefox is almost not working anymore, in Chrome it is a little better. Opening an image from my camera (18Mpix with the default image viewer) freezes my system for seconds... But the worst is videos: I cannot play any video full screen anymore with mplayer - my player of choice. VLC seems to be able to do better but I'm not seeing 30fps, everything stutters. This all worked fine a couple of weeks ago.

My GC is an old ATI (Radeon HD 4350/4550) and from what I've gathered it might be the problem... Is there a solution short of reinstalling my system with 13.10 ? Or switching to Windows because I'm tired of reinstalling my OS all the time...

I've got a Q6600 (quad core) with 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is now solved. This was not the updates that screwed over my performance, but the replacement of one of my screens (I have dual screen). I did both almost at the same time so I suspected the updates. The addition of the screen (and subsequent change in resolution) caused havoc on my system and after a reboot, everything is back to normal.